# Heroku Couldnt Find that app

Tags: heroku

I am working on linux terminal, when i try the command - heroku create
It works

```
Creating app... done, ⬢ frozen-plateau-26000
https://frozen-plateau-26000.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/frozen-plateau-26000.git
```

But when i try next to perform  heroku open
I get this

```
(node:23086) Error Plugin: install: files attribute must be specified in /home/user/.local/share/heroku/node_modules/install/package.json
module: @oclif/plugin-legacy@1.1.0
plugin: install
root: /home/user/.local/share/heroku/node_modules/install
See more details with DEBUG=*
(node:23086) [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK] @oclif/plugin-legacy: Plugin mvn: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
/home/user/.local/share/heroku/node_modules/mvn
 ▸    Couldn't find that app.
```

This is a spring boot application and here is part of my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
heroku open --app <app-name>
```

`--app` (alias: `-a`) is a required parameter for `heroku open`. Check `heroku open --help` for more details on the command usage.